# HTML Renderer - letter-spacing CSS not working

Tags: html, css, html-to-pdf, letter-spacing, html-renderer

I'm generating PDF from HTML using HTML Renderer, but the letter-spacing HTML is not working:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

Generating PDF like below:

```
    var config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
    config.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
    config.PageSize = PdfSharpPageSize.A4;

    string cssStr = File.ReadAllText(folderPath + "1.css");
    CssData css = PdfGenerator.ParseStyleSheet(cssStr);

    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, config, css);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    pdf.Save(stream, false);
    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

    File.WriteAllBytes(folderPath + "document.pdf", bytes);
```

Also tried inline CSS style, also not working:

```
<h1 style="letter-spacing:3px;">
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe one of these links could be useful?

- https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=5793
- https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9372

It seems as if you have to use the 'XTextFormatter' class to adjust word spacing in PDFsharp

I haven't tested it, but it seems the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. tried the XTextFormatterEx2 class, but code wouldn't compile as it's missing attributes in Xfont class

Comment: @Kris They are not using PDFsharp, so XTextFormatter does not help them,